# How to specifcy all results for each category level in gstsummary

Tags: r, gtsummary, tidy

I was wondering wether it is possible to get for all levels of Grade variable, as in this example, all regression results. Thus this would mean even including the values for level I of the Grade variable?

Example

```
library(nlme)
data(Orthodontic)
library(gtsummary)


  glm(response ~ age + grade, trial, family = binomial(link = "logit")) %>%
  tbl_regression()
```

In essence the question is: is it possible to add the results when Grade equal to I is not used as a referred, I mean for all the estimates computed by the model?

Comment: Please specify: which package is `tbl_regression()` from. Also, what data are you using? Give us a minimum reproducible example, for example by using built in example data sets or `dput()` your data. 
I suspect your question is more in the nature of "How do I interpret" the model output. In this case, it may be enough to just include the output at least in your question. Note that this is a borderline case to the domain of the CrossValidated forum, and statistics interpretation questions are more likely to be answered over there.

Comment: Even without the output, I can understand your confusion though. Usually, the first level of your categorical variable is used as *intercept* of the model...

Comment: I provided everything you needed. I asked here because in the function tbl_regression(), there is an option to specify both the intercept and the variable level used as refernce. So probably it is from here that my confusion comes from). According to this possiblities, it seems that intercept and reference variable were different things, while, as far as I knew and you seem to confirm, they are the same.

Comment: I am confused what exactly your question is. But perhaps this is useful context. The `tbl_regression()` just prints your model in a nice table: it does not modify the kind of regression/modelling being performed. The arguments `tbl_regression(intercept=FALSE, add_estimate_to_reference_rows=FALSE)` merely instruct the table to optionally include the intercept in the summary table and to add a dummy value to reference levels of categorical summaries.

Comment: If the description of these arguments is not clear enough in the function's help file, I suggest you run the function toggling these arguments between TRUE and FALSE. Then inspect the table, and I think their utility will become clear.